# JAXB Sub-Root Elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am confused about how to handle subroots in JAXB. I know that the root class looks like this:

```
package cool.java

@XmlRootElement
public class Snap {

    @XmlElement
    private Crackle foo;
    ....
}
```

And a subclass of Snap would look like this:

```
package cool.java

@XmlRootElement(namespace = "cool.java.Snap")
public class Crackle {

    @XmlElement
    private Pop foo;
    ...
}
```

Where I am getting confused is how to annotate the Pop class which has Crackle as its immediate root. Would I still just point it back to the main root?

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "cool.java.Snap")
```

Do I specify Pop's immediate root?

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "cool.java.Snap.Crackle")
```

Comment: AFAIK you would not need any special annotation (except `@XmlType`) , just reference `Pop` in `Crackle` (which btw is not a subclass of `Snap` but an element).

Comment: You do not need to specify anything this would suffice @XmlElement(required = true) or @XmlElement depending on you schema.

Answer (score 0):

You do not require any annotations on the `Crackle` class.  The contents of the `Crackle` instance will be nested with the element that corresponds to the field/property (i.e. `foo`) that holds the instance.

```
<snap>
    <foo>
       <foo>...</foo>
    </foo>
</snap>
```